# How to configure OpenMP for Visual Studio 2017 with Intel Compiler

Tags: visual-studio-2017, openmp, intel

I'm trying to use the OpenMP "collapse" clause in my project, but the clause was added in OpenMP 3.0 which Visual Studio does not support. So I installed the Intel C++ compiler and changed my project settings to use it, but it still gives the  build error `'collapse': unexpected token encountered on OpenMP 'for' directive` for the following code:

```
#pragma omp for collapse(2)
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        //unimplemented
    }
}
```

How should I configure my project to actually use the Intel compiler's version of OpenMP?

Comment: This is covered in icl instructions.   In the gui project setup is a select "use Intel c++" and also there is an Intel cmd prompt shortcut.

Comment: I've already selected the Intel C++ compiler for my project, as I said in the OP. It is still not recognizing the collapse clause though.

Comment: Except that if you had successfully enabled the intel compiler your code would be working, but it's not :-). I suggest compiling something that check an Intel specific macro, e.g. __INTEL_COMPILER_BUILD_DATE (so #if !defined(__INTEL_COMPILER_BUILD_DATE)\n#error not compiling with intel\n#endif

Answer (score 1):

u should right click on your project/source file:
properties -> language(intel c++ compiler) -> open MP support

Comment: The quoted error message  is from CL and doesn't resemble the warning throw in

Comment: The quoted error message from CL doesn't resemble the warning tthrown by icl when openmp is not enabled.  You're right about the requirement for the gui setting which sets Qopenmp.